# NoSuchElementException when page change

Tags: python, selenium

The code works until curPage=12 and it stops and show above error in curPage=13.
I tried By.XPATH & By.CSS-SELECTOR, but it doesn't work.
Also there is no frame to locate the element. 
Same XPath & CSS-Selector but doesn't work after page change. 
If anyone has idea, please save me.

```
url="https://home.kahis.go.kr/home/lkntscrinfo/selectLkntsOccrrncList.do"
time.sleep(3)
driver.get(url)
da = Alert(driver)

driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dissCl"]/option[13]').click()

driver.implicitly_wait(3)
date=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="occrFromDtId"]')
time.sleep(2)
date.send_keys("20170922")

driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="homeLkntscrinfoVO"]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]/a').click()

curPage = 1
totPage = 184
cons=[]
idx=1

while curPage<=totPage:

  driver.implicitly_wait(3)
  if curPage==1:
    da.dismiss()
  html=driver.page_source
  soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

  print('******* Current Page : ', curPage)

  trs=soup.findAll('tr', {'style' : 'background-color: #ffff80;'})

  for tr in trs:
    links=tr.findAll('td')
    for link in links:
      con=link.text
      cons.append(con)

  curPage+=1
  idx+=1
  if curPage%10==1:
    nextbar='//*[@id="homeLkntscrinfoVO"]/table[5]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[23]/a'
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, nextbar).click()
    idx=idx-10
  else:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#homeLkntscrinfoVO > table:nth-child(7) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child({}) > a'.format(1+idx*2)).click()
```

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-157-50e7fb0938ad> in <module>
     61     idx=idx-10
     62   else:
---> 63     driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#homeLkntscrinfoVO > table:nth-child(7) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child({}) > a'.format(1+idx*2)).click()
     64 
     65 driver.close()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    241                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    242             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 243         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#homeLkntscrinfoVO > table:nth-child(7) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(7) > a"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=105.0.5195.102)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that each xpath has its own element called 'onclick'. So I changed xpath as below and it works!!!

```
onClick='fn_page_link({}); return false;'.format(curPage)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@onclick, onClick)]').click()
```